# Why does make not see the rule?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a very simple Makefile and it gets stuck on `No rule to make target '%.o', needed by 'output.exe'.`

I only have 1 c file called main.c and it is in the same directory as my Makefile

My Makefile looks like this:

```
COMPILER_FLAGS = -g -Wall
COMPILER = gcc

all: output.exe

output.exe: %.o
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) %.o -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -c @< -o $@

clean:
    rm *.o output.exe
```

I have no clue why it doesn't see the rule. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not doing what you think it's doing:

```
output.exe: %.o
```

That is not a pattern rule.  A pattern rule must have a pattern character (`%`) in the *target* of the rule.  The pattern character may or may not be present in the prerequisites but it MUST appear in the target.  Otherwise, it's just a normal explicit rule.

Here you have told make that the target `output.exe` depends on a prerequisite file literally named `%.o`, and of course make has no idea how to build a file named `%.o` because you don't have a file named `%.c` or `%.cpp` or whatever.

Comment: Could you link me to some resource or explain how I would make a pattern rule for the output.exe?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  A pattern rule is a template that tells make "if you want to build a target that matches this pattern, and you can find or build this set of prerequisites, then you can use this command".  You don't need a pattern rule because you only want to build one target, `output.exe`, so you can just use an explicit rule for it (for example you can write it as described by Jib in their answer).

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful! In Jib's answer it seems like I have to add every c file to the `SRC` variable. With nested source files and a huge project this would be very tedious and that reason why I am using make is to not have to add every file. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Well, you haven't actually described what you want to do.  Your question is completely different than the comment you just provided.  If your question doesn't accurately reflect the actual problem you have, you should either edit your question (with the Edit button) or ask a new question describing that problem in detail.  However, it's not possible for make to intuit what object files you might want to create.  It won't go spelunking through your directories compiling everything it sees.  You have to tell it which files should be compiled, and which ones should be linked into which binaries.

Comment: If you want to just find every `.c` file and compile it and link it, you can use the `shell` function with the UNIX `find` command, like: `SRCS := $(shell find . -name '*.c')` and now the `SRCS` variable contains every `.c` file in every subdirectory of the current directory.

Comment: In reality any "huge project" of significant size probably has much more complex build requirements: it may want to link some libraries (static and/or shared), build multiple different programs, etc.  In general it's probably simpler to just keep a static list of source files in the makefile, then you know exactly which files go where.  How often do you really add an entirely new source file to the project, and is it such a burden to modify the Makefile when that happens?

Comment: Unfortunately for the project I want to build, you add them quite frequently. I understand that I should refactor my question and I am now trying to use Jib's approach, although it does not seem to work for me.

Comment: If you want a pattern rule for creating .exe files, it would be something like `%.exe: %.o`, though that would create the exe from  single object file of the same name.  If you want to link multiple source files into a single executable, you need to tell make how to find the sources you want (and only the ones you want, and ignore other source files).  You can use eg. `$(wildcard */*.c)` to find all the .c files in all subdirectories, but if you only want some, you'll need something more specific

Comment: Or if you have more than one layer of subdirectory, then that `wildcard` would not work.  Of course you can keep adding `*/` to it but no matter how many you add, someone might create more subdirectory layers.  The `find` option will search them all no matter how deep.

Answer (score 3):

Make does see you rule. Actually you have to tell make which source files must be compiled to objects:

```
SRC = main.c
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=%.o)

...

output.exe: $(OBJ)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me and I used a simple echo statement to see what OBJS contains. Turns out the variable is just a white space. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: @Mikachu: There is a small error in the [substitution reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs); it should be `OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=%.o)`.

Comment: Literally 5 seconds ago I realised that when looking at the docs. Thank you very much for all of your help!

Comment: @Beta Indeed, I switched equal sign with a comma.. I edited the post

Comment: @Mikachu I edited the answer so that the typo gets fixed. The solution now works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks to the help of @Beta I fixed this and thank you again for your help!